# Woocommerce getting custom field values in cart and checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I am trying to get the **custom field value of a WooCommerce product** to display **on different pages** of the shop system. I succeeded to do so for the single product page, but the same code doesn't work for the cart.

For the single product I used this code within the functions.php, which works fine:

```
global $post;
echo '<p>' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my-custom-field', true) . '</p>';
```

I tried the same code for the cart, but this time the values don't show on the page. I also referred to this thread ([Woocommerce getting custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374883/woocommerce-getting-custom-attributes)), changing $post to $product, but still no output...

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to include more code than that. Where are you placing this code? In some kind of product loop?

Comment: solved it: it's within a product loop, so the variable has to be `$_product`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'slug/id', true );
?>
```

You Can try this, This works for me Very well.