# How to get custom product attributes on custom product template in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've created a variable product using woocommerce plugin. In the variable product I've created a custom attribute "**License Duration**" with values "**3 Months | 6 Months | 1 Year | Life Time**".

Now I want to display this attribute on a custom single product template.

I've tried following solutions

**1.**

```
$licenseDurations = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'attribute_license-duration' );
```

This shows following on `var_dump($licenseDurations);` `

```
object(WP_Error)[558]
  public 'errors' => 
    array (size=1)
      'invalid_taxonomy' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Invalid taxonomy' (length=16)
  public 'error_data' => 
    array (size=0)
    empty`
```

and

**2.**

```
global $product;
$licenseDuration = $product->get_attribute( 'License Duration' ); // Here I also tried attribute slug `attribute_license-duration` instead of `License Duration` but no use
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13454788/2758870

and

**3.**

```
global $product;
$licenseDurations = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'License Duration');

foreach ( $licenseDurations as $licenseDuration ) 
{
    echo $licenseDuration->name;
}
```

in both of above cases I got nothing because `$product;` is returning `null` on `var_dump($product)`

**4.** I've also tried this code http://isabelcastillo.com/woocommerce-product-attributes-functions

by directly calling `isa_woo_get_one_pa()` where I want to show values. but with no luck.

Anyone here please help...

Comment: Product attributes start with `pa_` . In your first attempt, change `attribute_license-duration` to `pa_license-duration`

Comment: @AnandShah... I tried `pa_license-duration` but it is returning **Invalid taxonomy** error on `var_dump`. any other solution please

Comment: I have checked it locally by creating an attribute with the same name and it works fine.

Comment: @AnandShah... I dumped the database and did not find `pa_license-duration` attribute on search. Instead I found `attribute_license-duration`

Comment: That sounds strange, which version of WooCommerce are you using? Navigate to Products -> Attributes, click on "License Duration" and check the URL, what does the URL look like?

Comment: @AnandShah... I am not using attributes tab I am talking about creating variable products on **Add Product** page using **Product data** area and creating custom attributes in **attributes** tab of **product data** area and then using these attributes as variations in **variations** tab of **product data** area.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90875/discussion-between-angrycoder-and-anand-shah).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following

1.`get_post_meta` to get the product attributes

```
$attr = get_post_meta( 123, '_product_attributes' ); // replace 123 with the actual product id 
print_r( $attr );
```

2.Or you can create a product object and then using the `get_attributes` method

```
$p = new WC_Product( 123 ); // // replace 123 with the actual product id 
print_r( $p->get_attributes() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is changes in woocommerce, above did not give the attribute value. Following post from this [page](http://sarathlal.com/get-values-of-product-custom-attribute-woocommerce/) gave the correct answer

// replace `pa_attribute` with your attribute name, but keep the `pa_` prefix
// e.g. `pa_weight`

```
$fabric_values = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_attribute');

foreach ( $fabric_values as $fabric_value ) {
  echo $fabric_value->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are all product attributes listing:

```
$product_attributes = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_product_attributes' ); 
foreach ( $product_attributes as $group_attributes ) {
    foreach ( $group_attributes as $attributes ) {
      echo $attributes['name'].'=>'.$attributes['value'];
    }
}
```